# Installing any Laravel package on an AWS EC2 server shows warning and error messages even though the composer version installed Globally is latest

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, composer-php, laravel-package

[image]

I tried installing Laravel packages on my EC2 server on AWS via puTTY but everytime i run installation commands for a Laravel package, It shows a warning message (as shown in the image) and after that crashes with the same message:

```
In RemoteFilesystem.php line 560:

  The "http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2013%24373e592feb042f51b8ed82f090
  6531e330bdd926e48324f0393ad8c54afb6b5c.json" file could not be downloaded:
  failed to open stream: Connection timed out
```

It happens for every Laravel package. I have the latest version of composer (2.0) installed Globally in the standard linux server path: /usr/local/bin/composer. Can anyone suggest any solution?

Comment: Please share more details. Why do you even try to run `composer update` on any remote server? That's something you should avoid at all times. Also, loading packages over http is discouraged. Also, if you are really using the latest version of Composer, why should it warn you that you are **not** using the latest version?

Comment: It looks like your connection to packagist.org times out. You could try ping or curl/wget and probably get a similar result. Are you sure that your server is allowed to communicate outside its private network? In any case, you should probably take this to Server Fault instead as it is not a composer issue but rather a server/configuration issue